# How to make a WebSocket frame data to hide/mask

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, data-masking

Consider the following use-case:
Say I am making the socket request from the browser (consider socket object is available and status is connected):

[image]

So if you inspect in the developer tools of chrome/any browser, you will be able to observe something like below:

[image]

I was thinking there is a way to mask or send it in binary format how other messaging services are doing on web socket. I tried the following way to send masked/binary

[image]

But its showing again as below (it not masked/binary)

[image]

This is how it looks on the other messaging services.

[image]

I have tried to explore the full documentation on the socket.io npm module. But unfortunately did not find how to do this.

Can anyone put some light on this or any reference to the document link will be of great help.

---

**Updates**: I found this reference but not able to understand how it can be used on the library i.e. node module socket.io [Data Framing & Masking](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5)